# Issues in finding Node package when running Codebox

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, pty

After following the instructions to install Node and Codebox on our server, I get the following error when trying to launch Codebox:

```
Use GIT actor for auth: xxx@yyy.com
[log][web] disable auth for /static
Error in the application:
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/pty.node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/codebox/node_modules/shux/node_modules/pty.js/lib/pty.js:10:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
Error initializing CodeBox
```

I decided to installed pty.js with npm to try to fix this and made sure that it exists the the path outputted in the error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/codebox/node_modules/shux/node_modules/pty.js/lib/) but I still get this error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is how i've just solved this problem:

```
cd /usr/lib/node_modules/codebox/node_modules/shux/node_modules/pty.js
make clean
make
```

After this Codebox was successfully started.

Comment: This did it for me! Do you know what was causing the problem?

Comment: @nickdbush the module was not compiled. That is the reason why it was not found i think.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the error with NMP but not with the codebox itself, I had a similar problem and tried to fix it by the below steps :

1. Install node this way : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-an-upstream-version-of-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04
2. Then try to install **codebox** with out using the **sudo** even i don't know what the problem with **sudo** but haven't worked for me.

Hope it works.